# Scala Iterable to ParIterable

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, iterator

For a given iterator, for instance

```
(1 to 9).grouped(3)
res: Iterator[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = non-empty iterator
```

how to convert it into scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable ?

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/conversions.html

Comment: Note that, while conversions to `ParIterable` are possible, they require copying the elements if the collection is not directly parallelizable. In your case, the iterators are not directly parallelizable. Always measure to make sure that the copying step does not take more time than the work that is subsequently parallelized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `to` method to explicitly convert it to a parallel collection. For example, to make it a `ParVector`:

```
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector

(1 to 9).grouped(3).to[ParVector]
```

`Iterator` does not have a `par` method because there is no `ParIterator` - the parallel collections API needs the entire collection available in order to start dividing up work, so a `ParIterator` wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: Many Thanks, an illustrative explanation.